# Upgrade the OS from 5.x to 6.x

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, system, operating-system, zte

How can I upgrade from 5.1.1 to 6.x in order to utilize [adoptable](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200522/48164) storage?

Comment: What is your device? (Also, if you haven't gotten a system update through your device vendor, you probably won't get one (see [Is it possible to upgrade the android OS on all phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/832/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-the-android-os-on-all-phones?rq=1)).

Comment: You can check a custom ROM like Lineage OS.